# cant edit work mail in central admin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, sharepoint-email, outgoing-email

In the admin site (https://-admin.sharepoint.com/), click on User Manage Profile Service: User Profile Service Application> Manage User Properties
search  Work email. Scroll down to find Work email, and not able to edit it.

[image]

My problem is to map the mail for user profile, because i'm getting this error:

> The following users do not have e-mail addresses specified:

Comment: You can not change the user profile mappings in SharePoint Online

Comment: it's on premise

Comment: The URL says that this is not on-premise

Comment: @RobertLindgren I corrected the url .

Comment: If you are using IE11, you will need to add the CA site into your Compatibility View settings list. IE11 doesn't play nice with UPA by default. The dropdowns should re-appear after this., now it works fine

Comment: Just open your internet explorer by "Run As Administrator"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. open SharePoint center admin.
2. Click on Manage service applications.

[image]

3. Click on User Profile.
4. then click on Manage User Profiles
5. then Find your user Name
6. Right click on your User & Edit My Profile.
7. Edit user Profile & save it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sarika , my probleme is i cant edit :" 6.Right click on your User & Edit Ny Profile" i even have all permissions

Comment: If you are using IE11, you will need to add the CA site into your Compatibility View settings list. IE11 doesn't play nice with UPA by default. The dropdowns should re-appear after this., now it works fine

Answer (score 3):

If you are using IE11, you will need to add the CA site into your Compatibility View settings list. IE11 doesn't play nice with UPA by default. The dropdowns should re-appear after this., now it works fine